# ClassCastException when casting a base class object to an class that extends base class

Tags: java, constructor

I have ***mentioned comments along the code line , that I want to understand*** i.e. as follows:

1. I didnt't  understand this line of code :
   **`Xyz obj3=(Xyz) obj1;`**
2. `Abc` cannot be cast to `Xyz` type . Compiled , but returns exception during execution : **`Xyz obj2=(Xyz)new Abc();`**

   ```
   class Abc
   {

        Abc()

       {

       System.out.println(" Hello ");

       }

       void show()
       {
           System.out.println("Conco constructor w/ Super Class");
       }

   }

   class Xyz extends Abc

   {

       Xyz()

       {
           System.out.println(" Hi ");
       }

       void display()
       {
           System.out.println("ConsNew3 constructor w/ Extends Class Conco");
       }

       public static void main(String arg[])
       {
           Xyz obj=new Xyz();

           Abc obj1=new Xyz(); 
           obj1.show();

           Xyz obj3=(Xyz) obj1; // I didnt't  understand this line of code


           /*Xyz obj2=(Xyz)new Abc(); Abc cannot be cast to Xyz type . Compiled , but returns exception during execution */


       }
   }
   ```

Comment: for 2/ a dog is an animal but an animal is not always a dog

Comment: This does not seem to be about implicit or explicit constructors. It is about [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: @RC. Logical explanation , can help more than metamorphic approach . Hope , you don't mind briefing it ?

Comment: @khelwood , I would rather disagree . 

Going , with the code , class Xyz is a super class , while the class Abc is a sub class , that extends the Xyz .

Hence , object of Xyz type , will have both the method types ie of both Abc and Xyz , but can only use of type Xyz  , just like the implicit-explicit conversion , where the datas need to either non-primitive or primitive types .

Here , they are of type : NON PRIMITIVE , then how come polymorphism ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Xyz obj3=(Xyz) obj1;` this line works because `Xyz` is an `Abc`.

`Xyz obj2=(Xyz)new Abc();` this line does not work because not all `Abc`s are `Xyz`s

As the comments mention it can make more sense to name things this way.

> Abc == Animal
>
> Xyz == Dog

`Dog obj3 = (Dog) obj1;`

`obj1` was previously instantiated as a `Dog` although it is being held by a more generic `Animal` object. It still is an instance of a `Dog` so it can be cast back to a `Dog`.

`Dog obj2 = (Dog) new Animal();`

`Animal`s are not necessarily `Dog`s.

In order to avoid problems like this you can use the `instanceof` operator. This tests whether a generic Object is an Instance of another, usually more specific Object.

You can use this as follows.

```
Object myGenericDog = new Dog();
Animal myAnimal = new Animal();

if(myGenericDog instanceof Animal){
    myAnimal = (Animal) myGenericDog;
}
```

For future reference, in cases of both real and example code it is far more beneficial to the developer writing the code and any future developers who may end up maintaining the code to use *descriptive* class names. Note: `Xyz` and `Abc` are not *descriptive*. They introduce unnecessary complexity. You can improve your own code and examples by choosing names that are nouns and that describe the responsibility of your classes.

Comment: This was , very helpful . Thank you , with loads of respect and regards .

Comment: If for a moment , I keep the metamorphic part aside . " Not all animals are Dogs . Ok . " . Does , it mean that not all the methods of type Animal are compatible with those that of type Dog ?

Comment: @1ambharath that is correct, An `Animal` will have access to the methods on the `Animal` objectonly. A `Dog` will have access to both the methods on the `Dog` class and those on the `Animal` object.

Answer (score 2):

In general humans are not very good in abstract notation, although programs require that.

A beginner (more correctly any person) in programming should not use abstract names like Abc, and Xyz, this even confuses advanced programmers.

Why not just rename Abc to Animal, and Xyz To Dog.

Then you have:

```
Dog obj3=(Dog) obj1; // works because Dog is an Animal.
Dog obj2=(Dog) new Animal(); // does not compile because not all Animals are Dogs
```

Comment: Thanks . I agree , with you , too . Wish , I could have more than 1 answers as accepted .